# Connection refused on react docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, containers, connection-refused

I'm new ro Docker, i'm trying to dockerize my react application
- This is my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:latest AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install formik
RUN npm install axios
RUN yarn run build

FROM mhart/alpine-node
RUN yarn global add serve
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/build .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["serve", "-p", "80", "-s", "."]
```

- i build the container successfully:

```
docker build -t frontend .
```

- Then i run:

```
docker run 8000:80 frontend
```

- When i try to access to the server on:

```
localhost:8080
```

I get connection refused.
I don't know what i did wrong, Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should port forward with parameter `-p`, like:

```
docker run -p 8000:80 frontend
```